# Using Chinese characters in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a stored procedure that is called by a SSIS package. This package calls many stored procedures, but this particular one is the only one causing issues. Basically, I am converting a column in a table from `nchar` to `nvarchar` and putting those values into another table.

The values could be English, or they could be Chinese.

Here is the code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[TransformCustomer]
AS
    DECLARE @MapDimCustomer TABLE
                            (
                                 SourceSystemId INT,
                                 ExCustomerKey NVARCHAR(15),
                                 CustomerName NVARCHAR(115),
                                 CustomerTypeName NVARCHAR(50)
                            )

    INSERT INTO @MapDimCustomer (SourceSystemId, ExCustomerKey, CustomerName, CustomerTypeName)
        SELECT
            4 As SourceSystemId,
            c.ABAN8 As ExCustomerKey,
            c.ABALPH As CustomerName,
            c.ABAT1 As CustomerTypeName
        FROM
            F0101 c
        LEFT JOIN
            GlobalDW.stage.DimCustomer gc ON c.ABAN8 = gc.ExCustomerKey 
                                          AND gc.SourceSystemID = 4
         WHERE
             gc.CustomerID IS NULL;

    SELECT * FROM @MapDimCustomer;
```

So, where it says

```
DECLARE @MapDimCustomer TABLE
(
  SourceSystemId int,
  ExCustomerKey nvarchar(15),
  CustomerName nvarchar(115),
  CustomerTypeName nvarchar(50)
)

INSERT INTO @MapDimCustomer(SourceSystemId, ExCustomerKey, CustomerName, CustomerTypeName)
```

`CustomerName` is where it can be English or Chinese. When I run this, it turns the Chinese symbols into `?????`. I know that, if I were entering a customer name, I would have to use `N'Chinese Characters here'`. Is there a way to declare that?

Comment: I suspect that the datatype in F0101.CustomerName is varchar? That means the data in that table has already removed the Chinese characters and replaced them with ? because varchar doesn't support those characters. No level of converting or whatever can recover those characters...they are gone.

Comment: No, the data in F0101 is nchar.

Comment: So if you run just the select statement portion of your insert above you see the Chinese characters?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: OK, I ran the procedure again and it worked. Deleting this question.

Comment: Actually, and tell me if this should be a different question. The next column is ABDC, and it could be either a Latin translation of the Chinese characters, blank or just the same Chinese characters. My boss would like me to somehow check and, if ABDC is Latin characters, then use that to populate CustomerName, otherwise, just stick with the Chinese Characters in ABALPH. Is that possible?

Comment: You could check the UNICODE value of the first character and decide based on the result.

Comment: @SeanLange, don't want to sound stupid here, but I'm not quite sure how, or even where, in my code to do this check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an answer to your question about looking at the first character to determine the UNICODE value it would be something like this.

```
SELECT 4 As SourceSystemId
    , c.ABAN8 As ExCustomerKey
    , case when UNICODE(left(c.ABALPH, 1)) > 127 then c.ABALPH else c.ABDC end As CustomerName
    , c.ABAT1 As CustomerTypeName
FROM F0101 c
LEFT JOIN GlobalDW.stage.DimCustomer gc ON c.ABAN8 = gc.ExCustomerKey 
                                    AND gc.SourceSystemID = 4
WHERE gc.CustomerID IS NULL;
```